# Why does intellij idea not kill the debug process immediately?

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-idea, issue-tracking

I'm using **idea 2016.1.1** and wonder why idea does not kill the debug process immediately when I click the stop button.

E.g. use this piece of code to reproduce it

```
public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int i = 0;
    while (true) {
      i++;
      System.out.print("I'm still alive: ");
      System.out.println(i);
    }
  }
}
```

Set a breakpoint before the loop begins.

[image]

Start a debugging session, wait until it breaks and press the red stop button (CTRL-F2).

[image]

**I would expect that the process is stopped immediately** and that it does not print anything, but it prints:

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_38\bin\java" ....
Connected to the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:54394', transport: 'socket'
Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:54394', transport: 'socket'
I'm still alive: 1
I'm still alive: 2
I'm still alive: 3
I'm still alive: 4
...
I'm still alive: 319
I'm still alive: 320
I'm still alive: 321
I'm still alive: 
Process finished with exit code -1
```

**Why is the process not stopped immediately?**

**Is there another way to force an immediately stop?**

**EDIT**

Just tried it with **idea 14.1.5**. The process stops immediately as expected. It seems that a bug was introduced with 2016.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The bug [IDEA-155007](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-155007#u=1477664617398) is fixed in **2016.3 (163.7743.44)**. I've just verified it.

Comment: still happening for me with the latest.  Edit: nevermind, there's a setting mentioned here: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360000112384-Intellij-IDEA-doesn-t-stop-test

Answer (score 12):

When press `Stop` during a debugging session,
The default behavior of IntelliJ Idea *is **not to kill** the process immediately!*.

But if you need to change this behavior to kill the debugging process immediately
Which I think that, should be the default behavior :)

You can activate it via the Settings:
`Settings` > `Build, Execution, Development` > `Debugger` >

[image]

Comment: This has started happening to me on version 2020.3 on Mac OS 10.15.7. This setting has no affect.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. This functionality is working as of 2020.3.
Agreed the default behavior should be flipped since not immediately killing the process seems unintuitive and can lead to all sorts of nasty side effects.

Comment: IMHO this shouldn't be a config; we should have 2 distinct buttons, such as Stop the Debug session (which should kill the process immediately) and Detach from Debugger (which would continue the process). So the choice can be made at debug time.

Answer (score 4):

My investigations so far...

When IDEA starts a java process it uses main wrapper. This wrapper starts a daemon thread that listens to a `ServerSocket` for commands.

IDEA sends a `STOP` signal to that server socket. When the server thread receives the `STOP` signal it exists the jvm using `System.exit(1)`.

It seems that IDEA resumes the JVM from debug and then sends the `STOP` signal. So until the `STOP` signal is received the process continues.

I opened a bug at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-155007

Comment: ppl should vote on the youtrack issue if they want to see this bug fixed soon.