# intellij idea debug mode can not terminated

Tags: debugging, intellij-idea

when i use intellij idea debug mode, i set a breakpoints ,it paused where i set  successfully.when i do not want go on and push the stop button ,the process should be terminated . but the process carried on .for example.

```
    logger.info("fixGsDataAccount start");
    logger.info("before delete all cnt:{}",cnt);
    logger.info("query duplicate data include self  cnt:{}",cnt);
    logger.info("delete duplicate data end!");                            
    logger.info("after delete all cnt:{}",afterDeleteCnt)；
    logger.info("fixGsDataAccount end");
```

i set a breakpoints at the 3rd row .

```
logger.info("query duplicate data include self  cnt:{}",cnt);
```

and i push stop button , the log sholud shotp here like below ，

```
 05-07 17:57:47.536 [main] [INFO ] fixGsDataAccount start -
 c.wzt.web.datafix.FixGsDataAccount:33
05-07 17:57:47.540 [main] [INFO ] before delete all cnt:675 -
c.wzt.web.datafix.FixGsDataAccount:35
05-07 17:57:47.545 [main] [INFO ] query duplicate data include self  cnt:1 - 
c.wzt.web.datafix.FixGsDataAccount:37
```

but it show like below

```
    05-07 17:57:47.536 [main] [INFO ] fixGsDataAccount start -
 c.wzt.web.datafix.FixGsDataAccount:33
05-07 17:57:47.540 [main] [INFO ] before delete all cnt:675 -
c.wzt.web.datafix.FixGsDataAccount:35
05-07 17:57:47.545 [main] [INFO ] query duplicate data include self  cnt:1 - 
c.wzt.web.datafix.FixGsDataAccount:37
05-07 17:57:47.546 [main] [INFO ] fixGsDataAccount end - 
c.wzt.web.datafix.FixGsDataAccount:53
```

the last logger still print out

Answer (score 0):

Enable the **Kill the debug process immediately** option:

[image: kill]

Comment: Please share a sample project to reproduce it.

Comment: this guy has same problem with me.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36745457/why-does-intellij-idea-not-kill-the-debug-process-immediately

Comment: i not sure how to share with you , i think it's ide problem.not my code or other

Comment: This issue has been resolved and the current version is not affected.